# Failed to run hive query in airflow ui through data profiling(ad hoc query)

Tags: hive, airflow

I installed airflow following the official documentation. I tested it. Now I wanna to run some queries against hive. I have hive installed in the same host which operates successfully. I edited hiveserver2_default configuration is :

> ```
> Conn Type  : Hive Server 2 Thrift
> Host       : localhost
> schema     : default
> login      : hive
> password   : ****
> port       : 10000
> ```

---

So when I run any query in data profiling->ad hoc query, I got the following:

```
TExecuteStatementResp(status=TStatus(errorCode=1, errorMessage=u'Error while processing statement: Cannot modify airflow.ctx.task_id at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime', sqlState=u'42000', infoMessages=[u'*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:Error while processing statement: Cannot modify airflow.ctx.task_id at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime:27:26',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:toSQLException:Operation.java:335',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.HiveCommandOperation:runInternal:HiveCommandOperation.java:116',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation:run:Operation.java:247',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatementInternal:HiveSessionImpl.java:575',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:executeStatement:HiveSessionImpl.java:550',
u'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor95:invoke::-1',
u'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43',
u'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:498',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63',
u'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2',
u'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:422',
u'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1730',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59',
u'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy46:executeStatement::-1',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:executeStatement:CLIService.java:285',
u'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:ExecuteStatement:ThriftCLIService.java:567',
u'org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1557',
u'org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$ExecuteStatement:getResult:TCLIService.java:1542',
u'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39',
u'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39',
u'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56',
u'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286',
u'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142',
u'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617',
u'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:745'], statusCode=3), operationHandle=None)
```

I am stuck here. What steps do I have to take to solve the issue.

P.S. I could succesfully run query and get result from mysql db.

[image]

[image]

Comment: by any chance are you using `EMR`? because there we don't provide any password (leave the field blank). Also check that `localhost` can be used here (why not pass the private-IP of master?)

Comment: Hello @y2k-shubham. We use our own servers. I tried with/without password. Result is the same. So it happens to airflow default hive connector. Maybe I need to make custom connector. Could you please hint me how to make it?

Comment: Regarding `..So it happens to airflow default hive connector..` **[1]** what do you mean by `"connector"` here? `Airflow` [uses `PyHive`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L755) for `HiveServer2` **[2]** The `Connection` `SQLAlchemy` model in `Airflow` is completely *generic*: [`types`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L630) are only for end-user's benefit and `Airflow` distinguishes between connections [only on the basis of `conn_id`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/models.py#L613)

Comment: I add two images to explain what I mean by default hive connector (Maybe I wrongly use some words. Sorry).

Comment: @y2k-shubham,

I could find workaround. I made custom hive connection in hive.

However, I faced another problem. 

Could you please look at it too:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134669/cannot-modify-mapred-job-name-at-runtime-it-is-not-in-list-of-params-that-are-a