# could not open client transport airflow hiveoperator to connect

Tags: hive, airflow

```
Error: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://XXXX:10000/default;auth=none: Failed to open new session: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot modify airflow.ctx.task_id at runtime. It is not in list of params that are allowed to be modified at runtime (state=08S01,code=0)
Beeline version 2.3.6 by Apache Hive
```

I have tried to change parameter with hiveconfs to None but still getting issue

configuration which i have used :

Airflow connection is configure based on hive zookeeper based jdbc connection and used 'Hive client wrapper' as connection type.
Trying to pass some extra paramters to connect
extras : {"hive_cli_params": "","use_beeline": "true","auth":"none"}

**Sample dag code**:

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.hive_operator import HiveOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

dag_conf = DAG(dag_id = "airflow_hiveoperator",schedule_interval = None,start_date = airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1))


HiveOperator = HiveOperator(
    hql='hql/query1.hql',
    task_id = 'airflow_hive',
    schema='default',
    hiveconf_jinja_translate=False,
    dag = dag_conf,
    conn_id = 'hive_cli_default',
    hiveconfs=None
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dag_conf.cli()
```

Comment: This looks like the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55134669/2700344

Comment: No over here i have used different connection type and also different issue
i have tried that solution too.
But still struggling in that